# Non-parametric fit in R

Tags: r, data-fitting

I am struggling to find an appropriate package in R that would non-parametrically fit the line with some constraints (y should be between 0 and 1). Example:

```
y<c(0.102,0.073,0.067,0.062,0.059,0.059,0.063,0.064,0.067,0.073,0.070,0.070,0.069,0.074,0.075,0.066,0.074,0.072,0.064,0.054,0.057,0.040,0.019,0.010,0.002,0.001,rep(0,34))
x<-seq(1,60,by=1)

df<-data.frame(x=x,y=y)
plot(df$y~df$x)
```

Comment: When you want constraints, often the best approach is to transform your data. Typically when you want `y` bounded between 0 and 1, you use a logistic transformation on `y`, fit it using whatever unbounded non-parametric method you want (loess, splines, ...), and then back-transform it to the original range.

Comment: If you want a package that automates that, `mgcv` should work well.

Comment: Maybe `m <- lm(df$y~ poly(df$x, 12, raw = TRUE))`  and `plot(df$y~df$x,type="l");lines(m$fitted,col="red");grid()` . But it may end up with overfitting issue! So you'd better to check if it is ok with a test data.

Comment: Have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/np/vignettes/np.pdf

Comment: @maydin that doesn't address OP's ask *"...with some constraints (y should be between 0 and 1)"*

Comment: @GregorThomas Then you can easily take the absolute or the pmax value of the fitted values as the answer below. Not so big deal!

Answer (score 2):

**1) loess** Use loess as shown.  Vary span to vary smoothness.  No packages are used.  Truncate to satisfy the constraints. (The unconstrained values are all much less than 1 so we only need to handle 0.)

```
fm <- loess(y ~ x, span = 0.25)
yfit <- pmax(fitted(fm), 0)

plot(y ~ x)
lines(yfit ~ x)
```

(continued after image)

[image: screenshot]

**2) moving average** Any moving average whose filter coefficients are nonnegative and sum to 1 will necessarily be within the range of the data since it forms a convex combination of data points so as long as the data itself satisfies the interval constraint no special action needs to be taken to handle it.  Here we use a simple centered moving average as an example. Use the above plotting code but with the following for `yfit`.  Vary the width (here 7) to vary smoothness or use different filter coefficients satisfying the aforementioned rule.  Be sure that dplyr is not loaded since it clobbers filter.

```
yfit <- filter(y, rep(1, 7)/7)
```